# Running Master page scripts on imported page lines

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I'm importing some php into a div block using a link like this

`<a class="ajax-link" href="login.php">Login/Register</a>`

and such script (that uses jquery load to fill the div block).

```
$(function() {
    $("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#body-element").load(this.href);
    });
});
```

Now let's say the loaded php file after running the php portion also contains a link with "ajax-link" class and I want that link too to change the contents of that div block

```
<?php 
...
?>
<a class="ajax-link" href="view.php">View content</a>
```

But rather than running the above mentioned function on it, it seems to ignore it completely and opens a new page instead.

So basically... how can I run that script on imported parts of the page?

Comment: That second `a` element was not part of the DOM when you executed the code that binds the `click` handler. Go read the documentation for jQuery’s `.on` to see how you can have it include “future” elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is where event delegation comes in handy.

```
$(document.body).on("click", "a.ajax-link", function(e) {
    // ... 
});
```

Comment: Ooohh ... like this method.  Handles dynamically added OK?

Comment: Excellent answer! Yeah @rfornal - Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. From: http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I need to be able to favorite answers!

Comment: @rfornal You can favorite the question, and thus you'll always have the answer nearby. Just hit the star to the left of the initial question.

Answer (score 0):

This code needs to be re-run ... dynamically added objects are not included in previous on clicks.

```
$("a.ajax-link").on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#body-element").load(this.href);
});
```

... you could also ... turn off the old watcher.

```
$("a.ajax-link").off("click");
```

**UPDATE**:

Try ...

```
$("a.ajax-link")
  .off("click")
  .on("click", function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#body-element").load(this.href);
});
```

Comment: What would be the best method of re-applying the listener to the loaded content without duplicating the listener on the first link?

Answer (score 0):

You have to apply the click listener on the newly added link as well, as the element has to be loaded into the DOM when applying the click listener in order for it to be applied. However, if you just re-run the same code you'll like run into the problem of having two event listeners on the first ajax-link.

Try this:

```
// We still use on doc ready to be sure the 
// first link is present before applying listener
$(function() 
{
    // Reset all listeners on ajax-links and 
    // then apply listeners via function
    resetAjaxLinks();
});

// This function will remove any ajaxlink 
// listeners and then apply them correctly
function resetAjaxLinks()
{
    // Remove event listeners and then on click....
    $("a.ajax-link").off('click').on("click", function(e) 
    {
        // Prevent default link action...
        e.preventDefault();

        // Load in your content...
        $("#body-element").load(this.href);

        // Once content is loaded in, reset event listeners!
        resetAjaxLinks();
    });
}
```

EDIT: This is not the best method for this. Instead, use event delegation as specified by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27301644/3525315).